# parameter don't show on report pages on preview

Tags: c#, winforms, fastreport

I have multiple reports and every one has multiple pages. I want to merge them, set data source and parameter, and then show it in preview. However, only the parameter in the first page shows and the other doesn't show below. Is there a way I can merge my reports and set data source and parameter?

I asked the same question on fast report forum and searched google.

```
 var report = new FastReport.Report();
        foreach (var item in reportbytes)
        {
            using (var memoryStram = new MemoryStream(item))
            {
                report.Load(memoryStram);

                _report.Dictionary.DataSources.AddRange(report.Dictionary.DataSources.Cast<TableDataSource>().ToArray());
                _report.Pages.AddRange(report.Pages.Cast<ReportPage>().ToArray());
                _report.Dictionary.Parameters.AddRange(report.Dictionary.Parameters.Cast<Parameter>().ToArray());
            }

        }
        _report.RegisterData(dataSource, dataSource.DataSetName, true);

        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            _report.SetParameterValue(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
_report.Show(true);
```

how to fix this error? i expect shows parameter values on all pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i myself solve this problem and decided to write answer to helps our friends, every report should set parameters when it loaded

```
var report = new FastReport.Report();
foreach (var item in reportbytes)
{
   using (var memoryStram = new MemoryStream(item))
   {
      report.Load(memoryStram);
     ...
     foreach (Parameter parameterItem in report.Parameters)
    {
       if (parameters.ContainsKey(parameterItem.Name))
          report.SetParameterValue(parameterItem.Name,parameters[parameterItem.Name]);
    }
...
}

...
```